# Extent Reports: Screenshots not visible on report on jenkins.on local it is appearing proper

Tags: selenium-extent-report, extentreports

Screenshots not visible on report on jenkins,Screenshots are attached but not showing up.
however on local it is appearing proper.
I have already change the jenkins security rules.

Please find the screenshot of report

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the paths such as: ./snapshots/1.jpg' or snapshots/1.jpg'.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths for your screenshots.

```
htmlReport.config().setAutoCreateRelativePathMedia(true);
```